# Is there such a thing as "advanced" and "simple" English?

Tags: questions

Whenever I speak to my mum at home, she keeps claiming that my English is "simple" and I need to use harder vocabulary and speak "advanced" English. Is "advanced" English really a thing and is speaking in "simple" English as bad as my mum has made it out to be?

Comment: My impression to the "advance" English is literary words that we meet in some classical book.Btw, here is a ariticle (kind of) for you to impress your mother

Comment: @FunnyBunnyModl You may find our sister site, English Language for Learners (including second language students) more appropriate.

Comment: Some people complicate English unnecessarily. Others are lazy in their attitude to improving their linguistic skills. Obviously, fluency and a measure of precision are necessary (for instance, so that one can appreciate and adopt the anti-Covid measures governments put in place). Some careers need greater linguistic expertise than others, though the demands that appreciating say Shakespeare's writings make on linguistic skills are greater than those that enjoying say Enid Blyton are.

Comment: I think you meant to ask *Is speaking in "simple" English as bad as my mum **makes** it out to be?* (or feasibly ***made***), rather than ***has made** it out to be*. Not that there's anything *wrong* with using the Present Perfect there, but obviously it's a bit "advanced" compared to Simple Present (or Simple Past). My advice is *Do **not** try to improve your English by attempting to use "complex" structures and "uncommon" vocabulary*. Improve your English by seeking to express yourself as clearly and accurately as possible. If that forces you to use some new words or syntax, so be it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Technically, yes, there are forms of English that are designed to be simple, specifically for clear communication with people who have less proficiency in English.

For instance, **[Basic English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_English)** was developed by Charles Kay Ogden for teaching English as a Second Language, and **[Learning English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Learning_English_(version_of_English))** is used by *Voice of America* in their broadcasts. These simpler forms of English are distinguished by several features:

- A small active vocabulary list (850 words for Basic English, about 1500 for Learning English)
- Avoidance of especially idiomatic usage
- Simple, regular grammatical rules

Besides constructed dialects developed for specific purposes, however, there aren't "simple" and "advanced" Englishes. Instead, there are people willing to judge others' language usage on the basis of how they speak or write. For instance, a basic concept in *sociolinguistics* (the study of how society affects language) is *[prestige](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prestige_(sociolinguistics))*. Habits of pronunciation, word usage, phrasing, and other elements may accrue different levels of societal approval or prestige, relative to a specific group. In that sense, your mother may be marking a difference in prestige between how you speak and how she would prefer you speak.

Comment: Cf. *Pygmalion* (or, if we're feeling lowbrow, *My Fair Lady*)